# Is there a way to have the definition of a member function belonging to a variadic tempted class in a separate (.cpp) file?

Tags: c++, templates

I am aware of the conventional wisdom of put all your templates code in the header file, "it just works".

However I am a very big fan of clean nice looking header files. I want to know if there is a way to have a declaration in the header file and definition in a cpp file for any arbitrary template.

I specifically cannot get it to work in the case of a class possessing a variadic template with a non templated static member function.

From what I can work out with a "normal" templated class say:

```cpp
//in header
template<int bar>
class foo
{
    void member_method();
};

//in cpp
template<int bar>
void foo<bar>::member_method()
{
    ...
}
```

works fine however I cannot figure out a way of making the following work:

```cpp
//in header
template<int bar, int... args>
class foo
{
    void member_method();
};

//in cpp
template<int bar, int args>
void foo<bar, args...>::member_method()
{
    ...
}
```

This is my specific case:

```cpp
//in header
namespace awmms
{
    template<typename T, size_t num_segments, size_t, int chunking_stratagy, int... chunk_storage_sizes>
    class chunk_allocator
    {
        public:
         ...
        private:
            static void chunk(const int& segment);
            ...
    };
}
//in cpp
namespace awmms
{
    template<typename T, size_t num_segments, size_t, int chunking_stratagy, int... chunk_storage_sizes>
    void chunk_allocator<T, num_segments, chunking_stratagy, chunk_storage_sizes...>::chunk(const int& segment)
    {
        ...
    }
}
```

which generates the following compiler error:

```
/home/ebony/git/Ebony-Ayers/awmms/src/awmms.cpp:34:115: error: invalid use of incomplete type ‘class awmms::chunk_allocator<T, num_segments, chunking_stratagy, chunk_storage_sizes ...>’
   34 |         void chunk_allocator<T, num_segments, chunking_stratagy, chunk_storage_sizes...>::chunk(const int& segment)
      |                                                                                                                   ^
```

Any help with this example or insight into the whimsical world of templating would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: What you are doing is like having a `#define LOG(msg)` in a header file, and the implementation of the LOG macro `std::cout << msg << "\n";` in a source file.  The compiler *instantiated* the template when it is used, but if the compiler does not have the template available when it is *instantiated*, it won't have been expanded. The way I've seen "nice looking" done is to have a template implementation file, (I've seen `*.ipp` and `*.tpp` and `.tmpl.h` extensions used) which is `#include "foo.tmpl.h"` at the end of the `foo.h` file.

Comment: I second @Eljay Comment about putting the implementation into a `tpp` or `ipp` file and then include that in the bottom of you header file.  That lets you get separation, but it still Just Works®

Comment: @Eljay I am aware of that and that is what I was planning on doing if I could not find a solution here. I am just wondering if there is a conventional way of doing it.

Comment: The conventional way it to have the template implementation all in the header file.  The uncommon, but not idiosyncratic, way is to have the template declaration in a header and a template definition in a tag-a-long implementation header included at the end of the declaration header.  What does not work well (maintenance nightmare) is to have the template definitions *and instantiations* in a source file.

Answer (score 0):

You have to think about what the compiler has to do. The compiler has to generate code, and it's going to do so at the point you use the template, not the point you declare it. If you hide the implementation away in a .cpp file, then there's no way to generate that code for a specific usage.

The closest you can get to what you're trying to do is if your templated class inherits from a base class that's not templated, and then you might be able to do at least some of the work of the template class in the base class. That method is only get you so far, and probably nowhere near as far as you want it to.

In other words -- you can create a second include file and name it whatever you want, but it has to somehow get included anywhere you actually use the templated class. So even if it's not a .h file, it's still an include file.